# Files.write with list of Strings as argument fails in Scala REPL (2.10.5)

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

Working on some example code to create and write output to files using java.nio in scala REPL.  After the appropriate imports:

```
> import java.nio.file.Files
> import java.nio.charset.Charset
> import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
> import java.nio.file.Paths
```

I can successfully execute:

```
> val utf8:Charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8
> Files.write(Paths.get("foo.txt"), "foo".getBytes(utf8))
```

...and a simple file containing "foo" is created.  However, more in line with what I'd like to do (iterating over a list and writing each element as a line):

```
> val lines:List[String] = List("line1","line2")
> Files.write(Paths.get("bar.txt"), lines, utf8)
```

Fails with the following exception:

```
<console>:17: error: overloaded method value write with alternatives:
  (x$1: java.nio.file.Path,x$2: Iterable[_ <: CharSequence],x$3: java.nio.charset.Charset,x$4: <repeated...>[java.nio.file.OpenOption])java.nio.file.Path <and>
  (x$1: java.nio.file.Path,x$2: Array[Byte],x$3: <repeated...>[java.nio.file.OpenOption])java.nio.file.Path
 cannot be applied to (java.nio.file.Path, List[String], java.nio.charset.Charset)
          Files.write(Paths.get("bar.txt"), lines, utf8)
```

Trying the same with additional `StandardOpenOptions` fails similarly.

Can anyone help me understand why the write operation fails using a list of `String`?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that it expects a `java.util.List`. Try to import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._` and `Files.write(Paths.get("bar.txt"), lines.asJava, utf8);` (on 2.11.5)

Comment: @AlexisC. - this works.  Submit as an answer and I could accept it. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `Files.write` you're trying to match expects a `java.lang.Iterable` as argument and a Scala List does not implement this interface. So you have two options:

Use the signature that accepts a byte array as parameter by flat mapping the original list:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("bar.txt"), lines.flatMap(s => (s + Properties.lineSeparator).getBytes(utf8)).toArray)
```

or transform the Scala list as a Java list:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

...

Files.write(Paths.get("bar.txt"), lines.asJava, utf8)
```

Comment: I solved my issue using the second option here converting the Scala list using asJava.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here is Scala by itself cannot bring in the OpenOption interface. this library here https://github.com/scala-incubator/scala-io then your method call would be this.

```
Files.write(Paths.get("bar.txt"), lines.getBytes(), utf8, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
```

Comment: The solution in the above comment from @AlexisC. works and and does not require bringing in YAL (yet another library).  Thank you for the option but I'm going to opt for small and simple in this case.

Comment: Oh nice that's cool that worked.  +1 for cutting down on libraries.